# ¿Cómo sumar dependiendo de una condición en Python? Crear un dataframe con el resultado

Tags: python, base-de-datos, pandas, numpy

Tengo 2 dataframes: El primero con las listas 'valor' y 'número de identificación'. El segundo con 'celular' y 'número de identificación'. La lista en común que es 'número de identificación' no está ordenada.

**¿Como se hace un 3 dataframe que contenga 'celular' y la suma de los valores por 'número de identificación'?** Gracias por la ayuda

```
datos1 = {'Celular':['314','315','320','322'], 'Número de pago' : ['234242','23244','23242','243535']}
datos2 = {'Número de pago' : ['234242','23244','23242','234242','23244','23242','243535'], 'Valor' : ['100','200','300','400','120','2323','2321']}

dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(datos1)
dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame(datos2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer error grande que veo es que estás utilizando `dataframe2.Valor`, como cadena de caracteres.. lo primero a corregir sería transformar esa columna a un valor númerico.

El problema que planteas puede resolverse utilizando [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) Como bien aclara la documentación, *[...]funciones idiomáticamente muy similares a las bases de datos relacionales como SQL[...]*.

Para este caso se puede utilizar *inner join*.

Fíjate que la función recibe como parámetros dos *DataFrames*, la columna que funcionará como condición de join, y el tipo de join (*inner*, *left*, *right*, *outer*).

Además utilizo [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), para agrupar los datos por la columna *Celular* y asi obtener la suma del campo *Valor*, el reset_index() es solo para volver a aplanar el DataFrame.

```
dataframe2.Valor = dataframe2.Valor.astype(float)
resultado = pd.merge(dataframe1,dataframe2,on='Número de pago',how='inner').groupby('Celular').Valor.sum().reset_index()

resultado
```

| Celular | Valor |
| --- | --- |
| 314 | 500.0 |
| 315 | 320.0 |
| 320 | 2623.0 |
| 322 | 2321.0 |

Comment: Muchas, super claro. Perfecto

Comment: Sí la respuesta responde tu pregunta, te invito a que aceptes la respuesta clickeando el tilde.